# How do I know what type my variable is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I don't know how to determine type of a given variable while I read Python code. I would like to know the types of variables without the deep knowledge of methods that initialize values for them. Say, I have piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
n = 10000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)
xmin = x.min()
xmax = x.max()
ymin = y.min()
ymax = y.max()
```

How do I know what type `x` is? In Java it's simple. Even if I don't know the method, I know the variable type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#type) function to check the type of a variable.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
n = 10000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
print(type(x))
# numpy.ndarray
```

If, in the specific case of `numpy`, you want to check the type of your elements, then you can do

```
print(x.dtype)
# dtype('float64')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html#numpy.ndarray.dtype):

```
n = 10000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
x.dtype
```

gives:

```
dtype('float64')
```

---

If you want more detailed information on the [array attributes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#array-attributes), you could use [`info`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.info.html):

```
np.info(x)
```

gives:

```
class:  ndarray
shape:  (10000,)
strides:  (8,)
itemsize:  8
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  True
data pointer: 0xba10c48
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is a [dynamically typed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language) language. Technically, when reading code, you won't be able to know the type of a variable without following the code, or if the code is excessively simple.

A few quotes for you:

> Python is strongly typed as the interpreter keeps track of all variables types. It's also very dynamic as it rarely uses what it knows to limit variable usage.
>
> In Python, it's the program's responsibility to use built-in functions like isinstance() and issubclass() to test variable types and correct usage.

You can use `isinstance(x, type)` or `type(x)` to learn about the variables type information at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`type(x)` is straitforward answer. Normally you don't test type it through `type` but use `isinstance(x, type)` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

in the REPL (interactive console), you can also do

```
>>> help(x)
```

and it will display information about `x`'s class, including it's methods.